How to use Bindings in @Observable ViewModels in SwiftUI and MVVM?
I will be building my SwiftUI app using MVVM and the @Observable macro. I want to have some subviews with ViewModels that all have the same source.
In my example, I want the "sourceToggle" to be the source of truth and it will bind to the "bindingToggle" in the SubView.
When I press the button in the MainView, the text changes in both views, but when I press the button in the SubView, only the SubView text changes. How can I bind it so, that it changes in all views?
@Observable
class MainViewModel {
    var sourceToggle: Bool
    
    init(sourceToggle: Bool = true) {
        self.sourceToggle = sourceToggle
    }
}


struct MainView: View {
    
    var viewModel = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.sourceToggle ? "isOn" : "isOff")
        Button("Toggle1") {
            viewModel.sourceToggle.toggle()
        }
        SubView(viewModel: SubViewModel(bindingToggle: viewModel.sourceToggle))
    }
}


@Observable
class SubViewModel {
   var bindingToggle: Bool
    
    init(bindingToggle: Bool) {
        self.bindingToggle = bindingToggle
    }
}


struct SubView: View {
    
   @Bindable var viewModel: SubViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.bindingToggle ? "isOn" : "isOff")
        Button("Toggle2") {
            viewModel.bindingToggle.toggle()
        }
    }
}


I want the "sourceToggle" to be the source of truth – fine, but why do you create a second one?

You would be much better off learning that SwiftUI already is an MVVM and use View as the view model and learn State/Binding for dynamic data, computed vars for transforming data.

The issue was on this line:
SubView(viewModel: SubViewModel(bindingToggle: viewModel.sourceToggle))

You actually created another source of truth here, you just used the wrapped value in MainViewModel. I believe the correct way should be:
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var viewModel = MainViewModel() //<- here
    var body: View {
        ...
        SubView(viewModel: viewModel) //<- here
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
   @Bindable var viewModel: MainViewModel //<- here
   ...
}


@State is only for values or structs not classes because its a memory leak. You need to use @State var sourceToggle = false or @State var allTogglesStruct = AllTogglesStruct() and put the toggle in the struct as a var.

Thanks, yes in this example I would be fine if I have one ViewModel for both views, but in my project it would be advantageous if I have several ViewModels that contain sources and bindings. Do you have an idea how I could implement it?

Bindable is using for Observable, Binding is for value types

@malhal Observation supports from iOS 17, I've checked the adaptation documentation, isn't it StateObject -> State?

It's StateObject for classes (i.e. when you need a reference type lifetime) and State for structs. But since we have .task it now means StateObject is now irrelevant. In your case you should be using a struct but it doesn't make sense to call it a view model just name it based on the vars it contains.

May I suggest a simplified approach?
Using the below, subviews can be added with the @Binding var bindingToggle: Bool and they will all stay sync'd - togging the sourceToggle will toggle the bindingToggle in all of the SubViews and toggling bindingToggle in any subview will toggle sourceToggle in ContentView - and then in the other subviews.
This is not @Observable but it's not clear if that's being done to observe variable changes or another purpose. It's not needed with this code.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sourceToggle = false

    var body: some View {
        Text(sourceToggle ? "isOn" : "isOff")
        Button("Toggle1") {
            sourceToggle.toggle()
        }
        SubView(bindingToggle: $sourceToggle)
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var bindingToggle: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text(bindingToggle ? "isOn" : "isOff")
        Button("Toggle2") {
            bindingToggle.toggle()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

